# Can't login with existing user in the database ! - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, authentication

i'm working with ASP.NET web application and i have done a `Login.aspx` page , but whenever i tried to login nothing happen ! there's no error but nothing happne after i click the login button ! please any help ?

`Login.asp.cs` code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MyWebsite
{
    public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void ButtonS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString);
                conn.Open(); 
                string checkuser = "Select count(*) from Sellers where Username='" + TextBoxSUsername.Text + "'";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
                int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                conn.Close();
            if (temp == 1)
            {
                conn.Open();
                string checkPasswordQuery= "Select Password from Sellers where Username='" + TextBoxSUsername.Text + "'";
                SqlCommand PassCon = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, conn);
                string password = PassCon.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ","");
                if (password==TextBoxSPassword.Text)
                {
                    Session["New"] = TextBoxSUsername.Text;
                    Response.Write("DONE");

                }
                else { Response.Write("Wrong password "); }
            }
            conn.Close();

        }
```

and the `Login.aspx` code :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> Username</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSUsername" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="157px"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxSUsername" ErrorMessage="must enter username  "></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSPassword" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="157px"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxSPassword" ErrorMessage="must enter password"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td><asp:Button ID="ButtonS" runat="server" OnClick="ButtonS_Click" Text="Button"/></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This code is open to SQL injection, also, it is **very** bad practice to store passwords in plaintext like it appears your application is doing.

Comment: In addition to mituw16's points, you know there's an asp:Login control for all of this right?

Comment: @mituw16 yeah i know about the password i will change it later but i need to make the login work first

Comment: @Seano666 yes but i have to make a custom one because i have two types of users to login

Comment: @user5067119   I've seen 6 different types of users logging in using one login control.  Store the user type in the database and redirect after successful login based on that.

Comment: @Seano666 do you mean i add the types in 1 table ? and use it with login page ?

Comment: @user5067119  There are lots of ways to do this, yes if you didn't want to add a field to the existing table you could create a lookup table that just has the user id and "login type" field (whatever you decide that is).  Then join to that in your query.  The lookup table login type can then be used so the page knows where to redirect someone.

Comment: @Seano666 thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you debug the code? Seems like `temp != 1` and the code just close the connection.

By the way, that code has some problems. It's very inefficient to call twice the same query. Perhaps you can get all the information `(select * from Sellers)` and then ask for user and password, from the same data in memory.

Check the value of temp and try to `trim()` username and password first.

Comment: still not working after debug ! i used the same code with the registration form and it work fine i have no idea why this does not work !